# I'm trying to integrate HTTP requests to the web server which collects the data from my esp32 module

Tags: c, http, webserver

I need to `POST` the following line to the web server in C code so it establishes a communication between ESP32 and the required web server

```
// Prepare POST data
`char* post_data = "test_of_HTTP_POST_POST_some_text_for_test_HTTP_POST";
esp_http_client_set_post_field(client2, post_data, strlen(post_data));
```

The function definition of `GET` function is similar to the `POST` function shown here and that works perfectly fine. However, for the `POST` function, logs shows the `content length = -1`, `Buffer` as `NULL` and `total_read_len=0`. It updates the file I'm trying write on the server end with POST data but there is no response from the server.

PS: Server is correctly configured to handle both `GET` & `POST` requests.